# many to many relation gorm table

Tags: postgresql, grails, many-to-many

I have a little problem filtering data...I have a relation many to many.

**Sponsor and Old**

I have one intermediary table with both ids...

When I log in, my session save a Sponsor id...but when I go to see Old view, appears every Olds... How to access the intermediary table from the OldController or the SponsorController?

In my Oldcontroller I have:

```
def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)

        def sponsor = Sponsor.findById(session.getAttribute("id"))

        def myOld = Old.findAllBySponsor(sponsor, params)
        def allMyOld = Old.findAllBySponsor(sponsor)
        respond myOld, model:[oldInstanceCount: allMyOld.size()]

        //respond Old.list(params), model:[oldInstanceCount: Old.count()]
    }
```

But returns unexpected NullpointerException when processing request: [GET] /oldCare/old/index
No value specified for parameter 2.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No value specified for parameter 2.

How I access the intermediary table for filtering the olds and appears just the Old associated a one Sponsor?

Comment: if generated automatically from domain class the middle class should be names as a table like `sponsoure_old`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following :

```
  class Old {
        String title
        static hasMany = [sponsours: Sponsour]
    }

    class Sponsour {
        String name
        static hasMany = [olds:Old] 
    }
```

To find :

```
def sponsor = Sponsor.load(session.getAttribute("id"))

def allMyOlds = Old.findBySponsour(sponsor,params)
```

Comment: Yes I have the relation hasMany... in database, he create a intermediary table with both ids but when I don't know how access them

Comment: When I log in, my session save a Sponsor id...but when I go to see my list of Olds, appears all Olds (with my Sponsor Id and others)... How I filter that?

Comment: I have a Sponsor Domain and a Old Domain... The relation is many to many. I have a login and a session associated a ID Sponsor...when I go to the view the Old, appears every olds...Olds associated with that Sponsor (who make login) and others Old (associated an other Sponsor). U just want to appears the Olds associated at that Sponsor ID logged in